# Can QTCreator search for a specific warning or error and show all instances?

Tags: qt-creator, static-analysis

In example, let's say I want to search for all lines that have a warning about an extra semicolon (`;`). Can I search for that somehow?

I can easily look at the "issues" tab in QTCreator, but there's no way (as far as I know) to filter by type of issue. And if there are many, it's hard to find them.

Even more helpful, is it possible to search for macro-related issues, ie, `unterminated conditional directive` and show all files with an instance of it?

Comment: There exist a filter for such things and you can hide warnings:

[![Filter in issues][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN6Gz.png

Maybe it is hidden in your instance or you use a different QtCreator version?

Comment: I have the same options present there, except for the text input for the filter. I am on qtCreator 4.7.2. Is that extra filter a plugin or new feature?

Comment: I have 4.10.2. I think you should update your QtCreator. You might get that option as well then.

Comment: I don't have it in 4.9.0, so most likely that feature was introduced in 4.10.